# Match "fallthrough": executing same piece of code for more than one case?

Tags: scala

What is the Scala's way to write the following code:

```
 int i;

 switch(i) {
   case 1:  
         a();
         break;

   case 2:
   case 15:
        b();
        c();
        break;

   default: foo()        
 }
```

I.e. what is the idiomatic way of executing the same piece of code based on multiple case values?

```
 i match {
   case 1  => a    
   case 2  =>
   case 15 => { b
                c }
   case _ => foo        
 }
```

Doesn't quite seem do the trick, since Scala evaluates the match value based on the first matching case, i.e. if i=2 the code will return nothing.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to [this conversation](http://old.nabble.com/switch-case-fallthrough---td26030819.html) there is no fallthrough, but you can make use of `|`.

This should do the trick:

```
i match {
  case 1  => a    
  case 2 | 15 => b
                 c
  case _ => foo        
}
```

Comment: I removed `{` and `}` around `b` and `c`, to make it clear they are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. Did not think about this myself.

Comment: so obvious, yet so easy to miss

Answer (score 12):

Case statements can actually include additional logic guards using a standard if statement.  So you could do something like:

```
i match {
  case x if x == 1 => a
  case x if (x == 2 | x == 15) => b; c;
  case _ => foo
}
```

The matching guards can be any boolean function or composition of functions, so it gives it a lot more power than the standard switch statement in Java.

Comment: Note that if you prefer, there is no need for parentheses surrounding the guard condition in a `case ...` clause.

Answer (score 4):

While not applicable here, for more complex problems you can 'fallthrough' in a sense using the andThen function on partial functions.

```scala
 def do_function_a() { println("a"); }
 def do_function_b() { println("b"); }
 val run_function:PartialFunction[String, String] = { 
       case "a" => do_function_a(); "b"
       case "b" => do_function_b(); "c"
 }

 (run_function andThen run_function)("a") // a\nb
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with actual classes (instead of strings or ints), you need `_:` before each class to make them into a pattern before joining them with `|`.

```
sealed trait ShipCondition
case class ShipOnFire() extends ShipCondition
case class FoodSucks() extends ShipCondition
case class MateySnoresTooLoud() extends ShipCondition
case class Ok() extends ShipCondition

val condition = ShipOnFire()

def checkCondition(cond: ShipCondition): Unit = {
  cond match {
    case c @ (_: ShipOnFire | _: FoodSucks) => println("Abandon Ship!") // can also use `c` for something. It has the type ShipCondition
    case (_: MateySnoresTooLoud | _: Ok) => println("Deal with it!")
  }
}

checkCondition(condition) // Abandon Ship!
```

You get nice exhaustive checking too! Note that you cannot do case class destructuring when using alternative pattern matching (e.g. `case (MateySnoresTooLoud(str) | _: Ok) =>` will fail to compile.