# Match “fallthrough”: executing same piece of code for more than one case class?

Tags: scala

I have a function in Scala that matches different case classes, but executes the same code on every match. Is there a possibility to “fallthrough”? Or a other nice way to write the code bellow without code duplication and without defining a function?

```
symbol match {
            case Times(a,b) => //some code using a and b
            case Plus(a,b)  => //same code as above
            case Div(a,b)   => //again same code as above
}
```

This is a pretty similar too the question "[Match "fallthrough": executing same piece of code for more than one case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325863/match-fallthrough-executing-same-piece-of-code-for-more-than-one-case)" with the difference that I'm intressted in matching with case classes.

Comment: A named function? Extract to Tuple2 first, then process?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. But i search for another way. Coming up with a name for a function is hard ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own extractor that combines the three cases and turns them into a tuple:

```
  object BinOp {
    def unapply(op: Op) = op match {
      case Times(a, b) => Some(a, b)
      case Plus(a, b) => Some(a, b)
      case Div(a, b) => Some(a, b)
    }
  }

  symbol match {
    case BinOp(a, b) => 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! Exactly what I was searching for. My code is now so much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

No, falltroughs are prohibited in Scala since they are a common source of bugs in other languages. You have <s>two</s> three possibilites:

- factor out everything that is identical in a function
- try to use less specific matching, i.e., by using wildcards. In your example, this could also mean to introduce a superclass `BinaryOperation` which gives you the possibility of a more generic match. Note that due to case class inheritance restrictions, you would have to rely on using the fields of this superclass instead of having a super case class.
- follow Mirko Stocker's nice suggestions of writing a specific extractor.

Comment: Thanks, relay appreciate how you pointed out the different possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions to your problem

1) `unapply`

Extending on M. Stocker's answer, you could organize your data like so:

```
trait Op

trait BinaryOp extends Op {
  def a: Int
  def b: Int
}

object BinaryOp {
  def unapply(op: Op) = op match {
    case x: BinaryOp => Some((x.a, x.b))
    case _ => None
  }
}

case class Times(a: Int, b: Int) extends BinaryOp
case class Plus(a: Int, b: Int) extends BinaryOp
case class Div(a: Int, b: Int) extends BinaryOp
```

Usage:

```
symbol match {
  case BinaryOp(a, b) => f(a, b)
  case _ => //...
}
```

2) `Product`

All case classes extends the `Product` [trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product)

This allows you to do the following matching:

```
symbol match {
  case p: Product if p.productArity == 2 => {
    val a = p.productElement(0) //this has type Any, so a cast may be necessary
    val b = p.productElement(1)
    f(a, b)
  }
}
```

The second case is more generic, but it is also type-unsafe. I recommend the first solution.

Comment: Forgot to mention in my question that Times, Plus, etc. are in a library and I can not edit them. Thank you anyway for the nice write up.